# SQLite: trigger for multiple tables and/or multiple actions

Tags: trigger, sqlite

I am looking for a way to write [SQLite trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) which will affect multiple actions and multiple tables (in fact I want it executed on a particular table **each time any query is executed on any table** in the database).

---

Here is an example, to explain what I mean.
I have 3 tables: `Students`, `Courses`, `Professors`.
Each student has `activation_deadline` field, which is set to `NULL` upon activation.
I want each time any query is executed, to check if there are students with expired `activation_deadline` and if there are -- remove them.

Currently I have three separate triggers on `Students` table for this.

One for `UPDATE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Remove_Unactivated_Students_Update
AFTER UPDATE
ON Students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Students
    WHERE (activation_deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now'));
END;
```

One for `INSERT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Remove_Unactivated_Students_Insert
BEFORE INSERT
ON Students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Students
    WHERE (activation_deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now'));
END;
```

And one for `DELETE`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Remove_Unactivated_Students_Delete
AFTER DELETE
ON Students
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Students
    WHERE (activation_deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now'));
END;
```

What I would like, is something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Remove_Unactivated_Students
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON Students, Courses, Professors
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Students
    WHERE (activation_deadline IS NOT NULL) AND (activation_deadline <= strftime('%s', 'now'));
END;
```

Which, of course, gives me:

```
Error: near line 1: near ",": syntax error
```

---

Given what is said above, here are the questions:

1. Is it possible to write SQLite trigger for multiple tables, at once (if so how)?
2. Is it possible to write SQLite trigger for multiple actions (e.i. `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`), at once (if so how)?
3. Maybe there is a better way to achieve what I am aiming for?

Comment: *What I would like, is something like this:* I think that the only option is to create your own SQLite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, SQLite doesn't appear to have database or server level triggers (like other database systems). Instead you'd have to create the same trigger on each table.
2. Unfortunately this is also a limitation in SQLite and not possible either.
3. You might be better off letting the app that connects to the SQLite database (or a secondary process / job depending on if your database is stored on a mobile device vs a computer) control what records get deleted and when. For example, if you were hosting your SQLite database on a Windows machine, you could schedule a Task that routinely cleans up the database. Otherwise you can build it into the framework of your application that whenever a database call is made, the clean up script executes first.

Here is the [syntax tree](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/create-trigger-stmt.html) for the CREATE TRIGGER statement on SQLite. It may help clarify what you can and can't do.